# How to setup slurm on personal laptop?

Tags: configuration, slurm

I want to set up slurm on local machine (my laptop dual core).

[image]

Following is the specification. But i am not sure about nodename and cluster name during configuration.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, those names are SLURM internals. Use whatever you want. BTW, using your host name as node name is quite common.

Comment: Can i use manish-Inspiron-3542 as node? What about cluster name?

Comment: For the cluster name you can try "foo", "bar" and "baz". "Klaatu_barada_nikto" seems to be a good choice too.

Answer (score 2):

For the hostname, use the output of the command `hostname -s`. For the cluster name, you can choose whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks! what should i write for ControlMachine?

Comment: The same as the hostname. (`hostname -s`) Slurm compares the output of that command with what is in the configuration file to decide which role it must hold upon startup (controller, backup controller, or compute node)

Comment: Thanks but when i run sbatch i get sbatch: error: PluginDir: /usr/lib/slurm: No such file or directory
sbatch: error: Bad value "/usr/lib/slurm" for PluginDir
sbatch: fatal: Unable to process configuration file   how can i fix this error?

Comment: how did you install slurm?

Comment: I insalled using sudo apt-get install slurm and edited file /etc/slurm/slurm.conf after that but when i use sbatch i get sbatch: error: PluginDir: /usr/lib/slurm: No such file or directory
sbatch: error: Bad value "/usr/lib/slurm" for PluginDir
sbatch: fatal: Unable to process configuration file. Please help me.

Comment: Try to find where the DEB for slurm writes the plugin files and set that value for `PluginDir` in the `slurm.conf` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179091/discussion-between-manish-and-damienfrancois).